# Are uncountable nouns singular?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following correct (*those* referring to the uncountable noun *[information](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/information#Noun)*)?

> If SO reports on that information, what are the metrics on those?

Or should it be the following?

> If SO reports on that information, what are the metrics on that?

Or perhaps simply

> If SO reports on that information, what are the metrics?

[Context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90889/does-stackoverflow-measure-aborted-ask-question-attempts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly all uncountable nouns are singular. However, *clergy* and *gentry* are plural collective nouns that I believe are uncountable. For your question, *information* is singular, and both of your suggestions are correct, although the original is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think most uncountable nouns are singular, and certinaly "information" is. We ask, "Where *is* the milk?"; not, "Where *are* the milk?"

You answered your specific question already: notice that you're quite certain that the word "information" is immediately preceded by the word "that", not "those". Probably the third sentence in your example is the least awkward, and the second is flatly wrong. I'm not sure about the first, to be honest.

Comment: The first sentence is the original (from the context). The other two are my suggested sentences that might or might not be correct.